# Python 3 `os.walk` is way slower than a simple `find -type d`

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I need to find all git repositories in some folders. Previously, I used `find . -type -d -name .git`. Now I rewrote this in Python 3 and use `os.walk`. It seems to take way longer for it to traverse the tree than the simple `find`.

How can I speed this up?

Here is the complete code: [old](https://github.com/martin-ueding/maintenance/blob/v1.7.7/tasks/maintenance-git-autopush) [new](https://github.com/martin-ueding/maintenance/blob/v1.7.10/tasks/maintenance-git-autopush)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many threads about `os.walk()` on SO, it's dead slow.

- You may be interested in [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) (don't know if it's still applicable to python3)
- Instead of walking the entire tree and filtering for ".git", be a good chap and use the [glob-module](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html) to find them directly.

Comment: Okay, but how can I find them in arbitrary depth in the file tree with `glob.glob`?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the implementation of `find_repos()`, then using `os.walk()` is probably not optimal. The reason is that once you find `.git` subdirectory, there is no need to search deeper. Try to write your own directory traversal. You can have a look at the sources in `os.py` on how the `walk` is implemented -- the reason for *slowness* could be it is written in Python.

For other parts of your new solution... I have noticed that you do not compile regular expressions, but I did not checked details.

I suggest to separate the functionality to another Python script, then measure the solution using `timeit` module, and then try to optimize.

Comment: "no need to search deeper" - is that really true? What about sub-repositories ?

Comment: Do you use sub-repositories inside a git repository?

Comment: I build in a stop for that, actually. I do that with `dirnames = []`. Wait a minute ... that does not delete anything in the list. I'll change that. Although @pepr is right, I do have sub repositories.

Comment: @pepr Regexes could be compiled, but that is no performance problem, yet.

Comment: The subrepositories then should be captured as submodules in `.gitmodules` (but I do not use them, so I may be completely wrong). The `dirnames = []` does not change the `os.walk()` traversal. You only reuse the `dirnames` name.